# Asp.net web forms, Asp Identity - how to store claims from Facebook, Twitter, etc

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-identity, asp.net-4.5

How would one get this to work for standard Web Forms?

What I'm trying to do is populate the `AspNetUserClaims` table from the claims that I get back from Facebook (or other service).  I can see the values coming back in the OnAuthenticated, code below, how does one add those claims to the context of the currently logged in user?

---

Currently after the `OnAuthenticated` fires, it obviously returns me to the page (RegisterExternalLogin.aspx) as the built-in example provides.  However, the claims are gone, the context of the login to Facebook is gone.

How does one populate the claims FROM Facebook into the AspNetUserClaims table based upon the context of the currently logged in user WITHOUT using MVC?

```
        var fboptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        fboptions.AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        fboptions.AppSecret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
        fboptions.Scope.Add("email");
        fboptions.Scope.Add("friends_about_me");
        fboptions.Scope.Add("friends_photos");

        fboptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
            {
                foreach (var v in context.User)
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(v.Key, v.Value.ToString()));
                }
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
        };
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fboptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer to webforms directly, the process from MVC should be similar.

After log in, by using the external provider one is directed to a page where you register the new user.  After the postback from that page one has to add a line to all get the `ClaimsIdentity` again such as:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await
 AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync (
                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Without the call to this line above it did not work for me at all, so maybe that is where your problem lies.

Once one has the `ClaimsIdentity` iteration through the collection of claims on the `Claims` property of the identity can be done.  This should include the Facebook token you added in the OnAuthenticated callback delegate.  All you have to do then is call `UserManager.AddClaimAsync()` to add it to the Claims database table.

For more info look at my `AccountController` class at https://github.com/beabigrockstar/AspNetIdentitySocialProfileImage/blob/master/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Look specifically at the method

```
 ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model,
                           string returnUrl)
```

and the call to `StoreAuthTokenClaims()`, and then of course the process I follow in `StoreAuthTokenClaims()`.