# AspNet Identity AddClaimAsync never gets called

Tags: asp.net, facebook, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using asp.net forms and have written my own UserStore class that implements the Interface `IUserClaimStore<IdentityUser>` (and others), because I wanted to use AspNet Identity without EntityFramework and write my own data access layer for it.

Everything seems to work pretty good, but when I try to add Claims to my database tables I get problems.

In the `Startup.Auth.cs` I configure the FacebookAuthentication like this:

```cs
var options = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
options.AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
options.AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
options.Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
                       {
                          OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                          {                                 
                             foreach (var x in context.User)
                             {
                                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(x.Key, x.Value.ToString()));
                             }

                             context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                             
                             return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                          }
                       };

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

The `OnAuthenticated` method gets called and some claims should be added. But the `AddClaimAsync` method inside my UserStore class never gets called and so there are never UserClaim entries in my DB. At some point the `GetClaimsAsync` method will be called (I think during calling authenticationManager.SignIn(...)). So I think my UserStore should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're adding a claim to the ClaimsIdentity which is an in-memory object that represents the user from the external provider. You're not calling into ASP.NET Identity to store the claims in the database. To do so, you should be calling the AddClaim API on the UserManager.

Comment: But I can't call UserManager.AddClaimAsync, because I don't know the UserId at this point.

How can I access this ClaimsIdentity object from a later point? I have to access the claims from the page to which Facebook redirects the user (in my case it is the RegisterExternalLogin.aspx from the default asp.net forms website template).

Comment: So then issue a temp cookie and redirect the user to some .NET code to register them, then kill the temp cookie and issue the real cookie.

Comment: Ok, it worked with the cookie, but I've finally found the right way to do this (I think). In the callback page you can get the ClaimsIdentity with `ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);` --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819362/asp-net-web-forms-asp-identity-how-to-store-claims-from-facebook-twitter-et?rq=1)